# Crashlytics Gradle Plugin - Flavour dimension extra properties not working

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

I am using Crashlytics Gradle plugin latest version (09/03/2015). Extra properties for a flavour dimension to define groups, release notes or e-mails of a beta release are being ignored.

```
flavorDimensions "source", "type"

productFlavors {
    network {
        flavorDimension "source"
    }

    simulator {
        versionName "-SIMULATOR"
        flavorDimension "beaconSource"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_SIMULATOR_ENABLED", "true"
    }

    paid {
        flavorDimension "type"
        ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes="My Paid Release Notes"
        ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases="my_paid_group_alias"
    }

    free {
        flavorDimension "type"
        ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes="My Free Release Notes"
        ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases="my_free_group_alias"
    }
}
```

When I run the the following command:

```
./gradlew assembleNetworkPaidRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionNetworkPaidRelease
```

The extra properties information is ignored by crashlytics plugin.

If I move the extra properties to the BuildType it works:

```
release {
    ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes="My Universal Release Notes"
    ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases="my_universal_group_alias"
}
```

Comment: Thx, I've moved my declarations to default config. Unfortunately, Crashlytics/Fabrics documentation is very poor.